# Customizing navigation route widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `BottomNavigationBar` in my `widget`, when I want to show a new `widget` inside one of the items with `Navigator`, It shows a new screen on my last `widget`.

How can I replace my new widget with items of `BottomNavigationBar`?

Main Widget State:

```dart
class _MainWidgetState extends State<MainWidget> {

  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    HomeWidget(title: AppConstants.appName),
    ExerciseWidget(title: AppConstants.exercise),
    ProfileWidget(title: AppConstants.profile),
  ];
  .
  .
```

Profile Widget State:

```dart
class _ProfileWidgetState extends State<ProfileWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          onPressed: () {
            ViewUtils.openWidget(context, SettingWidget());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

`openWidget` in ViewUtils:

```dart
static void openWidget(BuildContext context, Widget widget) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => widget
        ),
    );
}
```

I need to `Navigator` shows my `SettingWidget` like `SupportFragmentManager` in Android: `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(..)`.

How do I do this?

**More Info**

I have Splash Widget that use `pushAndRemoveUntil` with `ModalRoute.withName('/main');` that Main Widget creates `BottomNavigationBar` with some items.

In one of them I click settings button which shows a new widget, this showing occurs with `Navigator.of(context).push` or `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement`.

Both of them shows my new widget on top of my main widget not replacing to one of my items in `BottomNavigationBar`.

Comment: Have you looked through the example of BottomNavigationBar from the flutter docs?: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

Comment: Yeah I read  `BottomNavigationBar` document, I need replace one of my items `widget` to another new one. `Navigator.push` creates a new `widget` in front of my Main Widget not replace it with one of my items in `BottomNavigationBar`. @LeonardArnold

Comment: Did you also looked into Navigation with named routes? https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes